# VMware vt-x incompatibility

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I have Intel E8400 cpu installed on system, as you know it's vt-x capable cpu, so i have VMware Workstation 9.0 and in vm settings it states do have support vt-x , but it doesn't work as expected, it has nothing against my system, vt-x capable cpu and it's enabled from BIOS

My question is: A) is it because of VMware version support, it means do I have to downgrade or upgrade version?
B) is it because of x64 guest OS or x64 host OS

I downgraded it to 8.0 and it seems to work, but i'm not sure
And one more interesting thing is vt-x works in VirtualBox.

thanks in advance

Comment: You say it does not work as expected. In what way does it not work?

Comment: when i try to start VM it shows a message saying "virtualized intel vt-x/ept is not supported on this platform". again i repeat, my cpu has vt-x and it's enabled in bios and one more thing vt-x works in virtualbox